# Calculated Field in Tableau for CTR

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a calculated field from a dimension "Notification type" which contains the data values "1" or "2" (1= impression, 2= click).
I want to calculate CTR(Click Through Rate) which is (clicks/impressions)*100.
Any solutions other than calculated fields are appreciated too. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data is one row per Notification Type you can do the following:

```
(sum(if [notification type] = "2" then [number of records] end)
/
sum(if [notification type] = "1" then [number of records] end))*100
```

Use quotes around 1 and 2 if notification type is a dimension (string).

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to mark the question as answered.